# When using FileOpenPicker, how to open the "Choose an app" screen like OneDrive app does?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, fileopenpicker

The new Windows Phone 8.1 file picker let us choose file from any place, but we must tap the ellipse at the picker toolbar and then "choose location" to be able to list files like the new OneDrive app does by default.

The screen I'm talking about is titled "Choose an app", and lists items like "Photos" and "Phone", that are native applications registered for file picker.

Same screen shown here, when the guy tap "Pick files" button
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=adR-lu8ZM6U#t=19

I want to open this screen by default, not the thumbnail view.
Changing the FileOpenPicker ViewMode property doesn't seem to have any effect.

My code is now just like this, I'm not setting ViewMode neither SuggestedStartLocation now:

```
private void OpenFilePicker()
{
    FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".avi");

    App.ContinuationEventArgsChanged += OpenFile_ContinuationEventArgsChanged;

    openPicker.PickSingleFileAndContinue();
}


private async void OpenFile_ContinuationEventArgsChanged(object sender, IContinuationActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    App.ContinuationEventArgsChanged -= OpenFile_ContinuationEventArgsChanged;

    var openFileArgs = e as FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs;

    if (openFileArgs != null && openFileArgs.Files != null && openFileArgs.Files.Count > 0)
    {
        //do stuff with the file here
    }
}
```

I'm supposing this should be a problem (from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker.suggestedstartlocation.aspx):

"The SuggestedStartLocation is not always used as the start location for the file picker. To give the user a sense of consistency, the file picker remembers the last location that the user navigated to and will generally start at that location."

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you added filetypes which are reserved by system and it causes that photopicker is launched. If you do something like that, it should work as you like:

```
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
```

There isn't any other solution.